# Javascript to restrict entry to numbers in textbox

Tags: javascript

I have an MVC form that I want to restrict the entry on some textboxes to numbers only. I found this code that does that, however, it also restricts the use of the numbers on the keypad pad on the right of the keyboard. Any ideas on how to allow the keypad? I am not sure what is causing that to happen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function ValidateNumber(e) {
           var evt = (e) ? e : window.event;
           var charCode = (evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
           if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
               return false;
           }
           return true;
       };
```

HTML Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerSSN, new { @placeholder = "Customer SSN", @type="number" })
```

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, HTML5 introduced `<input type="number" />`. It may not be a fit for you and the browsers you expect to support, but it comes with the behaviour you're seeking, and can be shimmed for older browsers. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html

Comment: @JeromyFrench - For some reason I could not get that to work?

Comment: Be sure to use the correct document header, ie `<!DOCTYPE html>`, in the very first line of output.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use the HTML 5 input tag that has built in validation.

```
<input type="number" name="quantity">
```

www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: I tried that and could not get it to work. I have edited above to show the razor syntax for the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I solved this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Allow only numbers entered
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CustomerSSN").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```